__builtin_FUNCSIG" is undefined error when integrating Boost with Visual Studio 2022
I'm working on a Windows 10 system using Visual Studio 2022 as my IDE. I installed the Boost library and integrated it into my Visual Studio project using the following commands:
vcpkg install boost
vcpkg integrate install

However, I'm encountering an issue. Whenever I include either of the following lines in my project:
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

I get the following error:
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error       identifier "__builtin_FUNCSIG" is undefined    D:\code\tool\test\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\throw_exception.hpp    224

Here are the detailed messages from the Visual Studio 2022 Output window:
1>        D:\code\tool\test\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost/throw_exception.hpp(224): error : identifier "__builtin_FUNCSIG" is undefined
1>
1>        1 error detected in the compilation of "E:/code/yhello.cu".
1>        yhello.cu
1>        D:\Visual studio\install_root\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 11.7.targets(790,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "D:\Visual studio\install_root\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\include" -I"D:\code\tool\test\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64\Debug\vc143.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o "E:\code\x64\Debug\yhello.cu.obj" "E:\code\yhello.cu"” exited with code 2.
1>      Task "CudaCompile" execution - FAILED.


I think that the issue might be resolved by using an older version of the Boost library, specifically Boost 1.70.0. However, I've found it challenging to install this specific version using vcpkg, as it defaults to installing the latest Boost version.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and not Visual Studio Code, which makes it less straightforward to use JSON configuration files or CMake scripts directly. I prefer a simpler method to install the Boost library and integrate it with Visual Studio so that I can develop and debug my project directly within the IDE.
Could someone guide me on how to install Boost 1.70.0 and integrate it into Visual Studio 2022?
Thank you for your help!

Do you have the issue on all programs or just cuda? You could probably define BOOST_DISABLE_CURRENT_LOCATION to avoid the issue.

@RetiredNinja Thank you for your guidance. Adding #define BOOST_DISABLE_CURRENT_LOCATION before:
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
resolved the error, and I can now build the executable. My understanding is that this macro disables certain functionalities of Boost within the current compilation unit. Is this correct? If so, I'm concerned that I might not be able to use some Boost features in future code. Can you clarify this?

@RetiredNinja
I think I understand now. I tested the functionality, and the Boost features are working correctly. However, when I continue adding ".cu" files, I still encounter the same issue. So, I added #define BOOST_DISABLE_CURRENT_LOCATION at the top of each ".cu" file, before including any headers, and this perfectly solved the problem.
My current understanding is that this line simply tells the nvcc compiler that Boost is not its concern and that the host compiler will handle everything related to Boost.

It just makes Boost not try to find the name of the current function on compilers that don't provide that info. Some messages might then say (unknown).
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html#boost_current_function
